# Mongoose- Updating a nested Array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am currently trying to update this MongoDB document with details from cloudinary.
I have gone through so many similar questions here on stackoveflow but no solution worked for me, hence i am asking mine.
Here is a copy of my schema file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const CarSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    Name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    Model: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    Year: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    engine: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    color: {
        type: String
    },

    status: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['available', 'unavailable'],
        default: 'available'
    },

    photos: [
        {
            imageUrl: {
                type: String
            },

            publicId: {
                type: String
            }
        }
    ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Car', CarSchema);
```

Now here is a copy of my Router.js file

```
router.put('/upload/:id', isAuthUser, upload.single('image'), async (req, res) => {
    // let car = await Car.findById(req.params.id);
    try {
        const result = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.file.path);
        console.log(result);
        // Updating thr car document
        const updatedCar = await Car.updateOne(
            {
                _id: req.params.id
            },
            {
                $push: {
                    'photos.$.imageUrl': result.url,
                    'photos.$.publicId': result.public_id
                }
            }
        );
        return res.status(200).json(updatedCar);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.stack);
        return res.status(500).json(error.stack);
    }
});
```

Here is the error i keep getting:

```
MongoServerError: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.
    at C:\Users\userpc\Desktop\CAR-HIRE-APP\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\update.js:85:33
    at C:\Users\userpc\Desktop\CAR-HIRE-APP\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection_pool.js:273:25
    at handleOperationResult (C:\Users\userpc\Desktop\CAR-HIRE-APP\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\server.js:327:20)
    at Connection.onMessage (C:\Users\userpc\Desktop\CAR-HIRE-APP\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:215:9)
    at MessageStream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\userpc\Desktop\CAR-HIRE-APP\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:63:60)
    at MessageStream.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at processIncomingData (C:\Users\userpc\Desktop\CAR-HIRE-APP\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:108:16)
    at MessageStream._write (C:\Users\userpc\Desktop\CAR-HIRE-APP\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:28:9)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:389:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:330:10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$push` stage is wrong:

```
{
  $push: {
           'photos.$.imageUrl': result.url,
           'photos.$.publicId': result.public_id
         }
}
```

`$` is a positional operator, which refers to the index of a particular element in the array. You don't need it. Try this:

```
{
  $push: {
           'photos': {
               $each: [
               {
                 imageUrl: result.url,
                 publicId: result.public_id
               }
               ]
             }
         }
}
```